# How to order by a non-model remote field like this?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, annotate, django-annotate

I have a table like this:

```
class SystemPushLog(models.Model):
    ...
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

As u can see in the model above, `user_id` is a `IntegerField`, not a foreign key. Cuz user infos in out system are retrieved from gRPC calls. Now, I wanna to order the queryset by `last_login` which is a field in user info.
I have tried with `annotate` like this in `get_queryset`:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset().annotate(
            last_login=self.__class__.get_user_last_login(F('user_id'))
        )
```

And below is `get_user_last_login`:

```
    @staticmethod
    def get_user_last_login(user_id):
        print('user_id', user_id)  # <<< user_id F(user_id)
        print('type of user_id', type(user_id))  # <<< type of user_id <class 'django.db.models.expressions.F'>

        # retrieving user info from rpc call.
        user = do_user_actions({'id': user_id})
        return user.last_login
```

As u can see, `F('user_id')` passed to the func is a type of `django.db.models.expressions.F` instead of a actual `user_id`.

Maybe `annotate` can just take some simple expressions like `annotate(off_price=F('original_price') - F('discount_price'))`.

So, how should I implement this remote field ordering?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a last_login field in SystemPushLog, by making last_login field nullable, you can populate last_login by overriding django `@classmethod def create()` then you can easily order your model since it has last_login field

I haven't tried this but something like this should work

```
def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'user_id' in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs['type'], int):
        # retrieving user info from rpc call.
        user = do_user_actions({'id': user_id})
        kwargs['last_login'] = user.last_login
    return super(SystemPushLog, self).create(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: But `last_login` is a field that will change as user logging in again, so I have to retrieve it dynamically. Otherwise I would do like you said.

Comment: @Gorgine That's true, but even if you are able to somehow pass F('id'), user.last_login will return non-expressions to QuerySet.annotate().

maybe you can populate the data everytime you request  get_queryset(self)?